# Store folder names into array and sort alphabetically

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is meant to pull each file name in a specific path and place it into an array. Although the files in the File Explorer are sorted alphabetically, the code is pulling them out of order.

My approach is to store the file names into the array, then sort the array. Is there a better way?

Additionally, the line with `Debug.Print arr1(i)` only prints blanks to the immediate window.

```vb
Dim arr1(1000) As String, item As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long, k As Integer
Dim TempTxt1 As String
Dim TempTxt2 As String
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
Dim size As Integer, i As Integer

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("X:\test\testfolder")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    arr1(i) = Left(oFile.Name, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(".", oFile.Name) - 1)
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print arr1(i)
Next oFile

'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    For y = x To UBound(arr1)
        If UCase(arr1(y)) < UCase(arr1(x)) Then
            TempTxt1 = arr1(x)
            TempTxt2 = arr1(y)
            arr1(x) = TempTxt2
            arr1(y) = TempTxt1
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```

Comment: Regarding the `Debug.Print` issue, move that line before `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Just so you know about this, you could also insert all into an `ArrayList` which has a `Sort` method you can call. If you pulling in these names one by one, you might as well pull them into this `ArrayList` which also doesn't need any starting dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as per my comment; I think you might benefit from using `ArrayList` and its ability to `Sort`. Try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, arr As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("X:\test\testfolder")
Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    arr.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)
Next oFile

arr.Sort

End Sub
```

Since you pull in names one-by-one we might as well do so in the `ArrayList`. The `.Sort` method will then sort the list in ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately I get "Run-time error '7': Out of memory" when I run this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just over 80-90 files. I created a test folder with only 4 files and still throws the same error

Comment: Side note, the `CStr(Split(ofile.Name, ".")(0))` stuff shouldn't be there. You want that to be just `oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)` (and ugh, drop that Hungarian Notation!!)